# React.js not incrementing after function call in onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to build a table in order to organize some data. I'm using the "onclick" function in order to call a separate function, which is supposed to increment a state variable up by one. My Chrome Devtools isn't giving me any errors but also isn't updating the stock variable. I'm not sure how to get the state to update and display. Here's my source code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            cars: [
                {
                    manufacturer: "Toyota",
                    model: "Rav4",
                    year: 2008,
                    stock: 3,
                    price: 8500
                },
    
                {
                    manufacturer: "Toyota",
                    model: "Camry",
                    year: 2009,
                    stock: 2,
                    price: 6500
                },
    
                {
                    manufacturer: "Toyota",
                    model: "Tacoma",
                    year: 2016,
                    stock: 1,
                    price: 22000
                },
    
                {
                    manufacturer: "BMW",
                    model: "i3",
                    year: 2012,
                    stock: 5,
                    price: 12000
                },
    
            ]
        };
        this.renderCar = this.renderRow.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState(() => {
            return {stock: this.stock + 1}
        })
    }

    renderRow(car, index) {
        return (
            <tr key={index}>
                <td key={car.manufacturer}>{car.manufacturer}</td>
                <td key={car.model}>{car.model}</td>
                <td key={car.year}>{car.year}</td>
                <td key={car.stock}>{car.stock}</td>
                <td key={car.price}>${car.price}.00</td>
                <td key={index}><input type="button" onClick={car.handleClick} value="Increment" /></td>
            </tr>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Manufacturer</th>
                    <th>Model</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Option</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.state.cars.map(this.renderRow)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
        );
    };
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make a separate component for the row, so that you can easily update that component to increment the `stock` value in state:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            cars: [
                {
                    manufacturer: "Toyota",
                    model: "Rav4",
                    year: 2008,
                    stock: 3,
                    price: 8500
                },
    
                {
                    manufacturer: "Toyota",
                    model: "Camry",
                    year: 2009,
                    stock: 2,
                    price: 6500
                },
    
                {
                    manufacturer: "Toyota",
                    model: "Tacoma",
                    year: 2016,
                    stock: 1,
                    price: 22000
                },
    
                {
                    manufacturer: "BMW",
                    model: "i3",
                    year: 2012,
                    stock: 5,
                    price: 12000
                },
    
            ]
        };
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Manufacturer</th>
                    <th>Model</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Option</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.state.cars.map(
                      (car, i) => <Row car={car} key={i} />
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
        );
    };
}
const Row = ({ car }) => {
  const [stock, setStock] = React.useState(car.stock);
  return (
      <tr>
          <td>{car.manufacturer}</td>
          <td>{car.model}</td>
          <td>{car.year}</td>
          <td>{stock}</td>
          <td>${car.price}.00</td>
          <td><input type="button" onClick={() => setStock(stock + 1)} value="Increment" /></td>
      </tr>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

You could put it all in one component if you had to, but it'd be a bit cumbersome. While rendering, you'd have to keep track of the render index of a row and pass that along to the click handler, then immutably update the `stock` property in the state array at that index. A separate component is easier.

Comment: Doesn't like this... Could it have to do with trying to call the row variable as a class, even though it's a variable? I'm pretty new to React so I'd like any info you may have. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, "Doesn't like this"? Are you getting an error? The code in the answer works just fine - press "Run code snippet" to see it in action. Press "Increment", and you'll see the `Stock` number for the row go up.

Comment: Weird - my local machine doesn't render the table at all. Must be because I'm going through a "bundle" script before this shows... not sure what the issue is, but your code works great. Thanks for the help, guess it's an issue outside of the code above.

Comment: Did you copy the JSX code in my answer exactly? If you do, it should work. If it doesn't work, you probably didn't copy it right (or you're using an ancient version of React and should upgrade...)

Comment: Thanks again - also new to stackoverflow :p

Answer (score 0):

```
   handleClick(e){
      const index = Number(e.currentTarget.value);
      this.setState(this.state.cars.map(car, i)=> {
        return i === index ? {...car, stock: car.stock + 1}: car 
      })
   }
 
   renderRow(){
    ....
       <input type="button" onClick={this.handleClick} value={index} />
    ...
   }
```